# Specify path to file for sys_create and sys_write in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to open a file in assembly using this code:

```
.data
filename: .asciz "/home/student/Documents/hw2"
file_descriptor: .quad 0

.text
.global main
main:
    # create output
    movq $85, %rax
    movq $filename, %rdi
    movq $0777, %rsi
    syscall
    movq %rax, (file_descriptor)
    ret
```

But I don't understand how do I put the PATH into filename? It won't create any file and it return -21 in return value (%rax).

I'm also trying to use the following code in order to read from existing file - but again, I don't see anything written inside digit (the place in the memory) after running this code (right before exiting).

```
.data
filename: .asciz "input.txt"
file_descriptor_in: .quad 0
digit: .quad 0
.text
.global main
main:
    # open INPUT
    movq $2, %rax           # save service number
    movq $filename, %rdi    # save path to file
    movq $0, %rsi           # save authorization level
    syscall
    movq %rax, (file_descriptor_in) # save file-descriptor number
    
    # read input
    movq $0, %rax                       # save service number               
    movq $file_descriptor_in, %rdi      # save descriptor of file
    movq $digit, %rsi                   # save buffer address to where the data will be saved
    movq $1, %rdx                       # save size of data to read
    syscall
    ret
```

I don't succeed writing either (I'm getting -9 return value)

I can't find any explanation online about how to use those command or what errors do they return. How can I learn to determine what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like it should work, and does here. That's assuming the directory `/home/student/Documents` exists, because the syscall will not create parent directories. You can use `strace` to log your system calls and use `man` to see what error codes mean and the include files for numerical values (but `strace` translates for you).

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @Jester I'm not even able to run it on gdb, I don't know why. and the directory do exsits

thank you both for your answers!

Comment: @fuz I'm working on vmware, it's just part of hw assignment for class, I just can't understand what's the problem since it's exactly what is written in our notes...
thank you both for your answers!

Comment: @E.Ginzburg vmware is not an operating system.  What operating system are you programming for.  Is it Linux?

Comment: The problem is probably that you have `movq $file_descriptor_in, %rdi` instead of `movq (file_descriptor_in), %rdi` by the way.  Error code 9 is `EBADF` (bad file descriptor), which sounds about right.

Comment: yes, It's Linux. I tried what you've proposed, and now I'm getting error code -14, do you know what does it mean? or where can I read more about the error codes? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Jester already told you to use `strace ./my_program` to trace system calls and decode error codes like `-9` being `-EBADF`.  Use that to find out what `-14` is.

Comment: @E.Ginzburg Read the `errno.h` include file.  It contains the numbers of all the error codes.  Refer to `man errno` for details on their meanings.  Error number 14 is `EFAULT` meaning an invalid address.  Which memory address you pass could be invalid?

Comment: @fuz thank you, I will check that. I found what's the problem: need to specify full path including the name of the file and the .* at "filename" in the data. thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: @E.Ginzburg Oh yeah, of course that needs to be the case.